# Lost entire MySQL Server. Unsure if "master-slave" or "master-master" - How to tell?

Tags: mysql, recovery, master-slave-replication

Yup - my db02 server lost a disk, and the array itself is corrupt (RAID5, yet corrupt data.) I was able to get the OS back online, but the corruption is severe.  I have zero documentation about the mysql configuration, other than a copy of the /etc/my.cnf file from the failed host.  (one small joy in this.)

1) How would I determine if it was in a m-s or m-m configuration?
2) Since I am lucky enough to have the /etc/my.cnf file, is there a clean way of restoring from the master?
3) Anyone have any other ideas as to what I should look for, in order to make sure what else needs to be put back in place?  Backups are managed via scripting, from yet another system.

Answer (score 0):

For M-M, both need to be masters and both need to be slaves.  Those need

```
log_slave_updates
log_bin
```

These should show something, even if not actively replicating at the moment:

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```

If you can't run things on the broken machine, then I suggest you do

- Clone the good machine's disk to the bad
- Change my.cnf to have a different server_id
- Turn on the two flags above
- `CHANGE MASTER ...` on both -- to establish being a Slave, and provide the pwd for the replication 'user'.

Now you will have Master-Master.  (There is not a lot of differences between M-S and M-M, so you may as well go for M-M.)

Comment: If the my.cnf does not contain "log_slave_updates", then they are not in a M-M setup, correct?

Comment: @RickJames would these 2 commands (show master and slave status) reveal the setup if they are run on the first, intact server?